# How to choose the second highest value of a patch variable in NetLogo 6.2?

Tags: netlogo

I'm having difficulty doing the following code: I have a piece of code that turtles inside an in-cone choose a patch that has resource > 30. When, the patch that turtle was the one that had the highest value a turtle did not move. So I put the line of code using the "other" command. However, what happens now is that if the patch the turtle is in has the highest resource value, it chooses another patch that has resource > 30. The problem is that there is, for example, a patch on the turtle's side that has resource value = 51 and another one that has a value of 31 and she chooses 31. What I would like to implement is: if the patch the turtle is in is the one with the highest resource value (and the turtle has already collected this resource) she would choose another neighbor patch that had the second highest resource value. I tried using max-one-of but got an error: "MAX-ONE-OF expected 2 inputs, an agentset and a number block.

Does anyone have any ideas, how can I solve this?

Thanks in advance

```
to go 
ask turtles
  [
    let availablePatch patches in-cone 5 90 with [ resource-value > 30 ]     
    ask patch-here [ set availablePatch other availablePatch ] ;; remove the patch it is in, because if the patch it is in is the one with the highest value within your range of vision, the turtle does not move      
   ; ask patch-here [ set availablePatch other max-one-of [ availablePatch ] ]
    let neighAvailable count availablePatch
    ifelse neighAvailable = 0
    [
      move-around
    ]
    [
      let target max-one-of availablePatch [ resource-value ]
      face target move-to target
      set step-count step-count + 1
    ]    
  ] 
end

to move-around
  right random 360 
  let step-length 2
  forward step-length
end
```

Comment: you should be aware that you create `availablePatch` in a turtle context, then change it in a patch context. this is always prone to error and unexpected results. It is unclear what `other` should mean in this context.

Comment: also it helps if you start by describing the program in more general terms (what is it supposed to represent, what are the turtles doing and why?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is often the case with new programmers, you are too far caught up in a specific thought pattern. So you are making the problem really technical and the code bloated, when code should always reflect what you are trying to do. What you want is simple, so the code should be simple. try to zoom out and think of other options.

If I understand correctly, turtles should pick high-resource patches to exploit them/gather their recources. But they should not pick the same patch twice.

possible solutions that make sense:

-after a turtle has exploited a patch, resources should be below 30. that way it won't be a candidate. if it is not below 30, moving doesn't seem to make a lot of sense anyway.

-use a patches-own variable "exploited" that you set to "true" after the turtle has moved there, and to "false" after the turtle has left. Then you can use `with [ resource-value > 30 & exploited = false ]`   instead of the current `with` check.

Comment: no problem, I hope I didn't come off as condescending. If these solutions work for you please use the green checkmark to accept the answer.